# Crash with my App store app on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

Thanks in advance for your help, after enabling my app on the store and loading it to my device it crashed immediately on my device (I had tested the app before on this and ~20 devices).

I used the same archive that I used when I submitted to the app store to generate an IPA file. I loaded that IPA file with iTunes and the app worked fine, switched back to the IPA file from the app store crash again. I noticed the file I created locally is 60% of the size of the file from the app store.

My questions are:

Is the same binary from the archive file is used in both cases?
If yes, what could be the reason I get a crash only with the IPA file I got from the store? (and also how come the size of the IPA file is so different?)
Can it be some conflict with  the provision profiles I used?

```
        Incident Identifier: FD536F0D-FD4C-4466-A045-1B0A0DD3B849
        CrashReporter Key:   4b62d59d09a52d8bfe7925b042bb7735b413f800
        Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
    Process:         SlimNavigator [318]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E84916D1-1EC4-410E-B0D2-54BAE94A7F0C/SlimNavigator.app/SlimNavigator
    Identifier:      SlimNavigator
    Version:         ??? (???)
        Code Type:       ARM (Native)
        Parent Process:  launchd [1]

        Date/Time:       2013-07-15 17:13:19.173 -0700
        OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
        Report Version:  104

        Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
        Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001
        Crashed Thread:  0

        Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
        Thread 0 Crashed:
        0   SlimNavigator                   0x00126d46 +[NSHTTPCookieStorage(DeleteForURL) deleteCookiesForURL:] (NSHTTPCookieStorage+DeleteForURL.m:20)
        1   dyld                            0x2fe346c4 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 16
        2   dyld                            0x2fe31a3a ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 382
        3   dyld                            0x2fe31874 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 36
        4   dyld                            0x2fe28d04 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 172
        5   dyld                            0x2fe2b85c dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 1804
        6   dyld                            0x2fe2832c dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 604
        7   dyld                            0x2fe28064 _dyld_start + 60

        Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000001    r1: 0x2fd73d3c      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x2fd73d68
    r4: 0x000000a5    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00126d55      r7: 0x2fd72b18
    r8: 0x2fe4a674    r9: 0x0000a100     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x1cd20fe0    sp: 0x2fd72ae0      lr: 0x2fe345b9      pc: 0x00126d46
    cpsr: 0x40000030

        Binary Images:
        0x8d000 -   0x227fff +SlimNavigator armv7  <65ab2d7c06c932f6b3925448d72d95bf> /var/mobile/Applications/E84916D1-1EC4-410E-B0D2-54BAE94A7F0C/SlimNavigator.app/SlimNavigator
        0x2fe27000 - 0x2fe47fff  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x32b1c000 - 0x32c02fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
        0x32c03000 - 0x32c03fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
        0x32c04000 - 0x32d42fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
        0x32d43000 - 0x32e26fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
        0x32e27000 - 0x330dcfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
        0x330dd000 - 0x33136fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
        0x33137000 - 0x33148fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
        0x33149000 - 0x33149fff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
        0x3314a000 - 0x3315bfff  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
        0x3315d000 - 0x331c1fff  AddressBook armv7  <8cfae84dc66d3c1f9d17335c53c3d7b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
        0x331c2000 - 0x3327cfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <0017d0a0c2593522acaaa0eee41775e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
        0x3327d000 - 0x3328bfff  AssetsLibrary armv7  <9a3a4a47a77833eb82a28757a3488660> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
        0x333c7000 - 0x3364ffff  AudioToolbox armv7  <394ee11cf826367db9ff4968dbc71d6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
        0x33650000 - 0x33715fff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
        0x33716000 - 0x3376cfff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
        0x33780000 - 0x33938fff  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
        0x33939000 - 0x33a6bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
        0x33a6c000 - 0x33ba4fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
        0x33de1000 - 0x33e96fff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
        0x33e97000 - 0x33eeffff  CoreLocation armv7  <4edb4b0f05e13af8b84699fe3ea4c538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
        0x33f24000 - 0x33f89fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
        0x33f8a000 - 0x34012fff  CoreMotion armv7  <4512d901170d32e7842e7fc1c519386b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
        0x34013000 - 0x34069fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bea09dbe25363c3b8e8016b5b5148055> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
        0x3406a000 - 0x340ccfff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
        0x340cd000 - 0x340dcfff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
        0x340dd000 - 0x34191fff  EventKit armv7  <99a7a1603323319f9e24f97e9f89bfd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
        0x34261000 - 0x34424fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
        0x345df000 - 0x34628fff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
        0x34629000 - 0x34801fff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
        0x34802000 - 0x3487afff  MapKit armv7  <027e730f45cc3868b98833546bb55449> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
        0x3487b000 - 0x34a15fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <ce97a30e514d3a17ae93ba4a9d1d69d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
        0x34a16000 - 0x34c90fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
        0x34c91000 - 0x34d17fff  MessageUI armv7  <8dbc0a8e6a253c8c8d6301064f23dfea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
        0x34d18000 - 0x34d71fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
        0x34e60000 - 0x34e67fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
        0x34e69000 - 0x34e69fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
        0x34e6d000 - 0x34e6ffff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
        0x34e70000 - 0x34e74fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
        0x34e75000 - 0x34eb2fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
        0x355ad000 - 0x356c2fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
        0x356c3000 - 0x35710fff  QuickLook armv7  <954e3a8bdaf337b085b30fd514ea5f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
        0x35711000 - 0x3573ffff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
        0x35740000 - 0x357adfff  Social armv7  <7b778c6ce3433df18ef0892acd831208> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
        0x357ae000 - 0x357bdfff  StoreKit armv7  <e63a14831d2d315ba5cf654102d67f8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
        0x357be000 - 0x357fdfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
        0x357fe000 - 0x357fffff  Twitter armv7  <ecae25ed2c893a969ceb0b911420c2be> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
        0x35800000 - 0x35d54fff  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
        0x35d55000 - 0x35d93fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
        0x35fe2000 - 0x35feefff  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
        0x36035000 - 0x36038fff  ActorKit armv7  <5dfc59258ea63006be9c542e5fafbc45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
        0x3603a000 - 0x3603dfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <c2a6c1ff89a9318d8b74fc5dfc8847b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
        0x36126000 - 0x36139fff  AirTraffic armv7  <752b64045f4d3ea88a946b53b731ce1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
        0x3613a000 - 0x36446fff  Altitude armv7  <d507155292c8341395d2cbde05ae448d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Altitude.framework/Altitude
        0x36469000 - 0x364a4fff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
        0x364a5000 - 0x364c9fff  AppleAccount armv7  <c54536fbc0f235f693060be33d4d4749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
        0x364d6000 - 0x364e3fff  ApplePushService armv7  <8bad4a9300db3d4d8555535f25c32da4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
        0x36517000 - 0x36520fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
        0x36521000 - 0x3653afff  AssistantServices armv7  <9608ae74229e3daeab9c8fcf679de7d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
        0x3653b000 - 0x36552fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log from your device? It's usually very telling & helpful.

Comment: First time check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14230961/1702413

Comment: Thanks, I just added the crash file

Comment: Thanks Tony, I tried to set the optimization level already but didn't manage to reproduce the issue

Comment: Can you also post the code from your DeleteForURL category on NSHTTPCookieStorage?  If you can't figure out why it behaves differently the next best thing is to fix the crash.

Comment: Thanks Kendall, It is inside a library, I can't change it but I prevent the call to it.

Comment: If this is the same application/crash as in your other question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664071/my-new-version-of-ios-app-crash-on-loading-only-when-loaded-from-the-app-store - then you should have updated that rather than post a new question.